# Primefaces prevent/disable editing in schedule

Tags: primefaces, schedule

How do you prevent editing/moving events on the schedule?
I could reset the date on the moveEvent() but this would not stop someone from dragging it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) DRAGGING: Use the draggable attribute of `<p:schedule>` set it to false or bind it to a bean property.

2) Editting: remove the listener from the eventSelect.

```html
<p:schedule value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" draggable="false" widgetVar="myschedule">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />
 <!--   <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="NOBODY" update="NOTHING"  Oncomplete="REMOVE ME" /> -->
    <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}" update="formNotificacao" />
    <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}" update="formNotificacao" />
</p:schedule>
```

PS: you did not specify PF version, i am using 3.3.1
PS2: if you leave the commented line your JSF may throw an error [www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-use-comments-in-jsf-2-0/](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-use-comments-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: waw didn't know it was that easy... Guess I used the wrong keywords to search for this issue :)

Comment: @VercauterenP its not easy, you were lucky someone was around that had solved that same problem earlier. Primefaces Schedule is a 12-head laernean hydra monster type. Good luck